# show in version name in applet Cache viewer

Tags: java, applet

How to show the version number in Java control panel?

Answer (score 2):

> How to show the version number in Java control panel?

System.out.println([System.getProperty("java.version")](http://pscode.org/prop/?prop=java.versionformat=TSV));

---

Or, for more complete information, see properties java.version, java.vm.version, java.specification.version & java.runtime.version.

### Sandboxed

Sandboxed values for properties [java.version, java.vm.version, java.specification.version & java.runtime.version](http://pscode.org/prop/?prop=java.version%2Cjava.vm.version%2Cjava.specification.version%2Cjava.runtime.version).

```
Name    Value
java.version    1.6.0_24
java.vm.version 19.1-b02
java.specification.version  1.6
java.runtime.version    unknown
```

### Trusted

Trusted values for properties [java.version, java.vm.version, java.specification.version & java.runtime.version](http://pscode.org/prop/?prop=java.version%2Cjava.vm.version%2Cjava.specification.version%2Cjava.runtime.version).

```
Name    Value
java.version    1.6.0_24
java.vm.version 19.1-b02
java.specification.version  1.6
java.runtime.version    1.6.0_24-b07
```

Comment: Ya' get that.  My edit was to address a further comment in your answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ cat test.java; java test
public class test {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
 }
}
1.6.0_24
```

I believe this will work in the control panel as it does from the command line.